# when I return access token in json it did not appears in the response - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am making an authentication api using Laravel passport
when I try to return the access token I get this :

```
"access_token": {
            "name": "authToken",
            "abilities": [
                "*"
            ],
            "tokenable_id": 60,
            "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-03T17:07:16.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-06-03T17:07:16.000000Z",
            "id": 12
        }
    },
    "message": "data has been retrieved"
}
```

I don't know where the token is
and this is my login controller

```
$rules =[
                'email' => 'email|required',
                'password' => 'required'
            ];


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'there is been an error', 'error message' => $validator->errors()]);
        }


        $loginData = $request->input();
        if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid credentials']);
        }

        $user = $request->user();

        $data['user'] = $user;
        $data['access_token'] = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response()->json([$data, "message" => "data has been retrieved"]) ;
```

Comment: Did you read Passport docs? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens
You need to hit `oauth/authorize` endpoint via guzzle or any similar http client in order to request a new token.

Comment: i read it but I used the same code in another project and it worked

Answer (score 1):

app/Models/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
//use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

make sure you have `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;` in User.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you have implemented all the necessary commands to work with laravel passport.
This makes it possible to take with a refresh token.
Try this:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Client as OClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;


public function login(Request $request){
    ....      
      // $laravelPasswordGrantClientId - this is the id of the client whose database you have
      $oClient = OClient::find($laravelPasswordGrantClientId);
      return response()->json($this->getTokenAndRefreshToken($oClient, request('email'), request('password')),200);
  }




public function getTokenAndRefreshToken(OClient $oClient, $email, $password) {
      $oClient = OClient::find($laravelPasswordGrantClientId);
      $http = new Client;
      $response = $http->request('POST', 'http://your.domain.com/oauth/token', [
          'form_params' => [
              'grant_type' => 'password',
              'client_id' => $oClient->id,
              'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
              'username' => $email,
              'password' => $password,
              'scope' => '*',
          ],
      ]);

      $result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
      return $result;
  }
```